# C# StreamWriter cant find File in the debug Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, path, writer

I want to to write to a File in my Project. The file is located in the Project under `Files/settings.txt`. On settings.txt I changed the Value to `Always Copy`.

In my Code I am getting a good looking Filepath, that looks correct to me, but it wont finde the File.
Here is the Filepath that I have and that the Programm cant find: `D:\VIsual Studio Project Folder\NikoManagementSystem\NikoManagementSystem\bin\Debug\Files\settings.txt`.

My Code is the following:

```
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Files/settings.txt");
    sw.Write(settingsString);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
```

I wanna write in this File, but I always get the `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` Error and It says that it cant find any file at `D:\VIsual Studio Project Folder\NikoManagementSystem\NikoManagementSystem\bin\Debug\Files\settings.txt`

Comment: Several things make that a somewhat dodgy approach: a) Several things can change the `CurrentDirectory` which could cause the code to crash. b) there is no Debug or bin folder for a deployed app and you may not have rights to play with files in the deployment folder location.  Better to use the `Users` folder because that is why they are there.

Comment: So you suggest me, that I create a new Folder(with my Program) for my Programm in the Users/MyUser Folder and then add all important Data like settings, etc. in this Folder. Am I right?

Comment: ...or you could use the `Settings` repository built into .NET

Comment: Okay, never heard of it, thats my First Real Project with C# right now. But it Sound interesting. Is this a Good Site to learn about the Settings Repository from .NET? https://revium.com.au/blogs/june-2012/creating-a-generic-settings-repository-in-c

Comment: @yaaaa About using `Settings`, you can refer to this documentation: [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). And what does `changed the Value to Always Copy` mean? Does it mean have set `Copy to output directory` property to `Copy always`? I've tested it, and everything works fine.